# unable to connect to wordpress repository url by tortoise svn

Tags: php, wordpress, svn, tortoisesvn

I want to submit plugin to wordpress plugin directory and i got approved and got a svn url of them to upload plugin files. Url look like that http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin-name/ and i can access from browser, when i type it, i really folders.I need to checkout to it by tortoise svn which i downloaded and installed version 1.8.4.
When i try checkout to that url by svn Gui i get errors like -

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
>   OPTIONS request on '/my-plugin-name' failed: 408 Request  timeout

please help me out asap

Comment: Googling the error message (which is always the best first step to take) suggests older versions of TortoiseSVN have this problem. eg http://reactos.org/archives/public/ros-dev/2013-July/016220.html (Edit: ah, I see you use 1.8.4 and did a fresh download...)

Comment: Did you change the my-plugin-name to your  plugin name?

Comment: At first it was not connecting.But after two hours, it's connected !! .I will come back if problem appears again